# Custom Router not working with IndexController in the same module

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, controllers, routing

I have a module with a custom router.
Here's the code:

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Module" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">22</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="testroute" frontName="testroute">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
        <route id="customrouter" frontName="customrouter">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Router.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    protected $actionFactory;
    protected $_response;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->_response = $response;
    }

    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        if(strpos($identifier, 'customrouter') !== false) {
            $request->setModuleName('testroute')-> //module name
            setControllerName('productlist')-> //controller name
            setActionName('index')-> //action name
            setParam('param', 3); //custom parameters
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return $this->actionFactory->create(
            'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward',
            ['request' => $request]
        );
    }
}
```

I have a breakpoint in the first line of the `match()` function:
`$identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');`

but this doesn't get triggered.

Instead the page is being loaded with an empty layout. (No 404 either)

I have a Index Controller in my module as well:
`Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php`

If I set a breakpoint in that Controller's execute function, the program stops there when I call my customrouter URL https://storeurl.com/customrouter

Is the Index Controller the problem here because it is being used instead of the Router? Or is the Index Controller just being used because there is another problem with the custom router configuration?

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by putting di.xml in `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml`
instead of `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml` like some guides tell you to.
Maybe those are for older versions of Magento, or just wrong.

Also make sure to do a `bin/magento setup:di:compile`